# How do I populate JComboBox from a text file?

Tags: java, text-files, jcombobox, populate

How do I populate a `JComboBox` from a text file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very vague question.  Are you saying you want one entry per line?  If so you want to use something like a BufferedReader, read all the lines, save them as a String array.  Create a new JComboBox passing in that String constructor.

```
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
try {
  String line = null;
  while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
    strings.add(line);
  }
}

catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Error, file " + filePath + " didn't exist.");
}
finally {
    input.close();
}

String[] lineArray = strings.toArray(new String[]{});

JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(lineArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) that reads a properties file to get keys (for the combo) and values (for a text area). See `enum Rule` in the [source](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite/source-code).

Answer (score 1):

Break down your requirements into separate steps and the code will follow:

1) read a line of data from the file
2) use the JComboBox addItem(...) method to add the data to the combo box