# Populating JCombobox with a text file

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I populate JComboBox from a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173149/how-do-i-populate-jcombobox-from-a-text-file)

I am new to programming Java  with only 2 months of experience. Can anyone help me to populate a `JComboBox` with a text file, consisting of 5 lines? I have looked at code on Google, but I keep getting errors.

Comment: *"I have tried many codes on google but always giving me compile errors."* It would be better to solve those errors. *"Please help."* Please ask a (specific) question.

Comment: i.e. Put your code that causes error

Answer (score 3):

```
private void populate() {
    String[] lines;
    lines = readFile();

    jComboBox1.removeAllItems();

    for (String str : lines) {
       jComboBox1.addItem(str);
    }
}
```

Here is readFile(). [From this site](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml)

```
private String[] readFile() {
  ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
  try {
     FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
     String strLine;
     while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        arr.add(strLine);
     }
     in.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  return arr.toArray(new String[arr.size()]);
}
```

Comment: And...how do you read a file...??

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: Don't quote code from roseindia. It is almost always wrong or poor code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think so too. I have just corrected a *compilation error* in their code