# display the text file item from certain column in jcombobox

Tags: java, string, swing, text-files, jcombobox

I am populating `jComboBox1` from data.txt file. I am using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368268/populating-jcombobox-with-a-text-file?lq=1) to populate `jComboBox1`.

The structure of text file as follows:

```
AAA 123456 BB                     22 Some text
AAA 234567 CC                     23 Some text
AAA 345678 DD                     24 Some text
```

The goal that I want to achieve is display in `jComboBox1` not all data, just certain column of data.

I found that `substring` can be appropriate choice.

For example as shown in below code, in `jComboBox1` I want to show data with position `substring(12,17) + substring(58,97)`.

```
     String data = strLine.substring(12,17);
     String data2 = strLine.substring(58,97);
     System.out.println(data + " " + data2);
```

But unfortunately I don't know how to achieve this goal.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Exactly which bits of each line are you trying to extract? Also, the lines are only 46 characters long, so `strLine.substring(58,97)` will throw an error.

Comment: @moarCoffee There I showed just sample of text file and without full line. But in my text file lines above 100.

Comment: Ah I see. Do the lines always have the same length/same format? If so, what's wrong with using `substring()' to get the bits you want?

Comment: @moarCoffee Length is same. Problem is I don't know how to show exctracted column in JComboBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368268/populating-jcombobox-with-a-text-file?lq=1) which you linked to, you could alter it to do something like this:

```
private void populateCols(int a1, int a2, int b1, int b2) {
    String[] lines;
    lines = readFile();
    jComboBox1.removeAllItems();

    for (String str : lines) {
       jComboBox1.addItem(str.substring(a1, a2) + " " + str.substring(b1, b2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. Your answer is accepted.