# Java in netbeans

Tags: java

I have taken combobox with null values,but I want to read data from text file,that I have created one text file has emo.txt,There I have all the details of the employees.

I want only employee ID  in combobox.How to fetch only ID in combobox??

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question and focus on giving a clear description of the problem. You will also need to include your code for us to be able to help you.

Comment: see this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173149/how-do-i-populate-jcombobox-from-a-text-file